# Fatal error while importing new table into existing database in phpMyAdmin 2.9.2

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

it is my first post on stack overflow :)
I have got Fetal Error while I am importing the 174 KB MySQL table data into the existing database. I am importing it through SQL (tab in phpMyAdmin) Query.
can anyone please help me out to handle this issue.
I have got the following fetal error.
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 50463 bytes) in D:\AppServ\www\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sqlparser.lib.php on line 306

Regards:
Abdul Sattar

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you're out of memory in your PHP process. You may need to change the limit in `php.ini`.

Comment: @Amber what setting would we need to change in file php.ini?